# Binding Autocompletebox Text

Tags: c#, telerik

I know Autocompleteboxes generally are for binding items and selected items.
But what If I enter text in it and the item doesn't exist. And I want to bind it to a string variable is that possible?

For example

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Text="{Binding Value}"
```

MVVM side

```
public string Value {get; set;}
```

Comment: I've done something very similar to this with normal combo boxes and it is possible. I've never used the telerik control though, is it specific to that control?

Comment: Is it about WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: It's WPf sorry wasnt clear

Answer (score 1):

Use **SearchText** property instead, e.g.:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox
     x:Name="acb"
     SearchText="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to sync changes between view and viewmodel.